# #error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build

I encountered an error in Visual Studio, `Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds`
so if I undefine the `_AFXDLL`, will my program go wrong?

Answer (score 50):

Settings for CRT linking and MFC linking must be coherent. So, actually, there are two possible answers at this question:

1. Use /MT (Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation) and static MFC (Properties -> General -> Use of MFC)
2. Use /MD (Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation) and shared MFC (Properties -> General -> Use of MFC)

Comment: For the most common cases this should be the solution. But if you are creating a AFX extension DLL then you MUST use /MD.
You are creating a AFW extension DLL when _AFXEXT is defined as preprocessor variable.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it will.  What you should do is is go to your Visual Studio project properties.  In Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation make sure you are using the Multi-threaded Dll for your Runtime Library.

That will solve your problems.