# What does preprocessor `_AFXDLL` mean?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I've searched but didn't hit a meaningful explanation, like what's the effect, the mechanism, so I could understand it. An example for "meaningful explanation", there are quite some materials online explaining `_DEBUG` preprocessor, how turn it on will allow `assert` etc.

MSDN page #1 [Building Settings for an MFC DLL for Visual Studio 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235516%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says this is not for 1) Regular DLL, statically linked to MFCrequired, but required for 2) Regular DLL, using the shared MFC DLL, or, for 3) Extension DLL. But there's no further explanation.

MSDN page #2 [AFXDLL Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f20edzb.aspx) briefly mentioned:

> Instead of building your application by statically linking to the MFC
>   object-code libraries, you can build your application to use one of
>   the AFXDLL libraries, which contain MFC in a DLL that multiple running
>   applications can share. For a table of AFXDLL names, see DLLs: Naming
>   Conventions.
>
> Note: By default, the MFC Application Wizard creates an AFXDLL
>   project. To use static linking of MFC code instead, set the Use MFC in
>   a static library option in the MFC Application Wizard. Static linking
>   is not available in the Standard Edition of Visual C++.

, but I'm even not sure if this `AFXDLL` is related to `_AFXDLL` preprocessor.

Stackoverflow post [Unexplainable error "Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963397/unexplainable-error-please-use-the-md-switch-for-afxdll-builds) and [#error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229120/error-please-use-the-md-switch-for-afxdll-builds) explained that `/MT` or `/MTd` conflict with `_AFXDLL`, but this is the same as the MSDN page #1, nothing new.

Could someone pls explain

- what does `_AFXDLL` preprocessor mean? the original motivation?
- how does it affect the compiling or linking?
- is it obsolete?
- is `_AFXDLL` preprocessor related to the `AFXDLL` libraries? and actually, what is this so called "AFXDLL library"?

Comment: Just an educated guess: Isn't `_AFXDLL` defined by the compiler when you are compiling against an AFXDLL? Just so you can add target-dependent functionality.

Comment: what is AFXDLL?

Comment: As the documentation states, when you are using the MFC libraries, you can either statically link them to your executable, or you can use them from a shared DLL. With an AFXDLL build you'll be using them from a shared DLL.

Comment: "from a shared DLL"... which DLL? if I'm not developing a DLL, but an EXE, shall I set `_AFXDLL` or not?

Comment: The concept is that when you use a library there will be a lot of compiled code outside of what you have implemented. Like, for example when you use MFC classes, these will have an implementation somewhere, not in _your_ code. These implementations will have to be _linked_ with your executable in order to work. You can achieve this in different ways, one way is to link the MFC code with your executable statically, meaning that the compiled code will be added to your _exe_ and be a part of it. You can ship your exe with the MFC code inside it that you are using.

Comment: An other way is to keep the MFC implementation away from your exe, and have your executable load these functions from a DLL, this MFC or AFX (same name) DLL (or DLLs) files will sit somewhere else on the user's system (usually next to the _exe_ file or in the Windows/System directory. MFC allows you to link their implementations both ways.

Comment: where is this AFXDLL? i did a `dir afx*.dll /a /s` and hit nothing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MSVC++ provides an optimization for programmers that want to deploy only a single executable file. You can build with /MT to link the C runtime library and the standard C++ library into the EXE. And you can link the static MFC libraries to link MFC into the EXE.  Not uncommon for small LOB apps.

Nice, but that cannot work properly when you also use DLLs to modularize or share your code or favor faster build times. MFC (and the CRT) have lots of global state, the CWinApp singleton is a good example.  A C++ program does not run in a VM like Java or C# apps do, *one* of the modules has to take responsibility to store that global state.  And the other modules must use that module's globals, not their own.  So you must use the DLL version of MFC and the DLL version of the C and C++ runtime libraries, and link their import libraries, they take on that responsibility.

And you have to tell the compiler about it, so that the library will go looking for the right place for those globals.  That requires #defining `_AFXDLL`.  Read it like "the application framework lives in its own DLL".  The CRT has a macro for that as well, it is `_DLL`.

Do note that this is completely automatic in the IDE.  Project > Properties > General, "Use of MFC" setting.  If you pick "Use of MFC in a Shared DLL" for this setting then you automagically will also get `_AFXDLL` defined.  Same for the CRT.

Comment: Is this completely automatic in the IDE? In Project > Properties > General, "Use of MFC" setting, I pick "Use of MFC in a Shared DLL", but I still don't see `_AFXDLL` defined under Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor?

Comment: You'll have to look a bit deeper, it is *inherited* from a project property sheet.  In VS2015 click the dropdown button of the setting, Edit, shows up in the "Inherited values" box.  It is also visible in the C/C++ > Command line > All options box.