# Static variables in static lib vs dynamic dll

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm not too sure of how to ask this, so please comment if I'm being unclear about something.

I have a project which uses a custom class called CManager. Most of my classes in this project inherit from this one and in CManager() (constructor), I add one to the count of CManager object, the count being a static variable in this class. Now, this project used to be compiled as a .dll (dynamic library), but my employer asked me to compile it as a .lib this time, while stripping away a lot of code. Now I have stripped away all the code that wasn't needed and compile it without error... But, when I am creating a .lib, I get an error when I try to execute the program saying that there is an unhandled access violation reading. Here is the code

```
int CManager::m_count = 0;

CManager::CManager()
{
    ++m_count;    <- Exception here
}
```

I don't know why I have this error. m_count is a private static int variable declared in the .h.
Since I didn't understand why it wasn't working, I tried compiling the project as a .dll, just so I wouldn'd be doing nothing. And for some reason... it worked. It compiles AND execute (run, wtv).

Now my question is... why is this happening? What explains this?

PS: This project has to include 5 other projects' .lib (or dll), but it work either ways. This project is included by my main, and it is when I try to execute my main that I get the error. The project is just a bunch of algorithms, my main app being the GUI. My main app is an MFC app.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:
While debugging, I found out that if I import the project using a static lib, when passing from my main's function call to the .lib implementation, I loose the object: I call a function on my object, and when I'm in the function, the value of this (refering the object) is null.
If I used a dll, it works perfectly. The object keep its value when a function is called on it.

But I still want to use a .lib, so I don't really know why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202142/static-variable-initialization-over-a-library

Comment: Well my variable is explicitly used, isn't it?

Comment: When you say that the *"variable [is] defined in the .h"* did you actually mean *defined* as opposed to *declared*?

Comment: Sorry I meant declared, I'll edit.

Comment: There's nothing in the code posted that would cause a problem. The only way to get into the function with `this == NULL` would be a problem in the place where the function was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Like Mark Ransom said in the comments, the problem was not in the code, it was in my project properties. I was creating a .lib instead of dll, but didn't change the runtime library accordingly. So in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Runtime Library, I started using MD and it worked.

Also make sure Runtime Library and general use of MFC are compatible, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229120/error-please-use-the-md-switch-for-afxdll-builds) for details.
I'm still not to sure of how using MT created problems, but at least I can run my program now.

Comment: I love being right, but in this case I was only half right. I still expected the problem to be in the code, not the project settings.